# trying to connect to MSSQL server using named pipe in HeidiSQL

Tags: sql-server, heidisql

I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL server in our office from my local desktop using HeidiSQL. I am able to connect to this server with both SQL Server Management Studio and ODBC with no problems. The connection uses integrated Windows authentication. I installed the MS OLE DB SQL 18.2.2.0 x64 driver. My settings in HeidiSQL are:

**network type:** Microsoft SQL Server (named pipe)

**library:** MSOLEDBSQL

**hostname:** <server>\<instance>

use windows authentication is checked

every time I try to connect I get:

> SQL Error (0): SQL Server Network Interfaces: Server doesn't support requested protocol [xFFFFFFFF] Login timeout expired

It doesn't tell me what protocol is being used, and I don't see any options to change it. Does "protocol" in this case refer to the library?

Is there some way to change the protocol in Heidi?

Comment: Hi @raphael75, Just want know, is there any limitation in SSMS compare to HeidiSQL, what made you to think using HeidiSQL instead of SSMS for SQL server ?

Comment: @ShekarKola HeidiSQL has several features that I really like. The ability to easily transfer data between tables and even databases, and the ease of viewing data make Heidi much better. There are some more advanced SQL Server-specific things that Heidi doesn't currently handle, but for basic stuff I find Heidi to be much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

1. Enable **Named pipes** visa configuration manager
   [image]
2. Restart particular SQL Service
3. Have a look at SQL log (recent entries after restart), it must state the named pipe is ready without any error (as showed screenshot below)
   [image]
4. If SQL error log looks good, try again with named pipe, make sure the `hostname` match with named pipe (configured in step:1)
   [image]

If still no luck, you may proceed with TCP/IP protocol, just make sure you are able to do `telnet localhost 1433` to be sure the TCP/IP is enable and ready for connections. If any issue, you can follow **Step 1 and 2** for enabling TCP/IP, and add a `New Rule` at Windows Firewall to accept incoming connections on SQL Port# (default: 1433).

[Additional steps for custom port configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244398/185080)

Answer (score 1):

To use named pipes it needs to be enabled on the server. You can check and enable this on the system with SQL Server installed by opening the SQL Server Configuration Manager software and checking the `SQL Server Network Configuration` section.
You can see how to do that [here](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm).

Give connecting a go using TCP/IP. The SQL Server Configuration manager will show you if that's enabled too. Then you can try connecting with the hostname and Windows Authentication. [TCP/IP](https://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2015/11/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using.html). Hopefully HeidiSQL hasn't changed too much from the images used in that link.

As an alternative to Heidi, should you need it, [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) is perfectly suited to all things MSSQL. It's also free!

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, the version of SQL Server they have here is much newer than the one in the first link you sent. I don't see any of those network configuration options in Server Manager 6.3.9600.17238 (build date 11/21/2014). Also, I mentioned in my post that the connection works perfectly in SSMS and in DSN/ODBC. It's only Heidi that I can't get it to work.